# What's the difference between catch {} and catch {continue;} in a c# foreach loop?

Tags: c#

```
foreach (Widget item in items)
{
 try
 {
  //do something...
 }
 catch { }
}


foreach (Widget item in items)
{
 try
 {
  //do something...
 }
 catch { continue; }
}
```

Answer (score 20):

`catch { continue; }` will cause the code to start on a new iteration, skipping any code after the `catch` block within the loop.

Answer (score 9):

The other answers tell you what will happen in your given snippet. With your catch clause being the final code in the loop, there's no functional difference. If you had code that followed the catch clause, then the version without "continue" would execute that code. `continue` is the stepbrother of `break`, it short circuits the rest of the loop body. With `continue`, it skips to the next iteration, while `break` exits the loop entirely. At any rate, demonstrate your two behaviors for yourself.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    catch
    {
    }

    Console.WriteLine("I'm after the exception");
}

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    try
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }
    catch
    {
        continue;
    }

    Console.WriteLine("this code here is never called");
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In that case, nothing, since the try is the last statement of the loop compound statement.  [`continue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/923ahwt1%28VS.80%29.aspx) will always go to the next iteration, or end the loop if the condition no longer holds.

Answer (score 3):

The compiler will ignore it. This was taken from Reflector.

```
public static void Main(string[] arguments)
{
    foreach (int item in new int[] { 1, 2, 3 })
    {
        try
        {
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
    foreach (int item in new int[] { 1, 2, 3 })
    {
        try
        {
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably an optimization done by the compiler. it is very specific to the above example code. if there were statements after the catch block (in the second foreach loop ), then you should probably see a continue. So you cannot say, continue is ignored always.

Comment: @SysAdmin - I am curious as to why you made this comment when no where in my answer do I mention that `continue` will always be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

If your sample is followed verbatim, then, I would say "no difference"!

But, if you have statements to be executed after your catch then it is a different game altogether!
`catch { continue; }` will skip anything after the catch block!!!
`catch{}` will still execute the statements after the catch block!!